# Merge two Binary trees

Tags: binary-search-tree

```
public int merge(BNode node, int array[], int i) {
    if (node == null)
        return i;
    //Flatten left subtree
    i = merge(node.left, array, i);
    //Get data from the current node
    array[i] = node.value;
    //Flatten right subtree
    i = merge(node.right, array, i + 1);
    return i;
}
```

I'm trying to merge two binary trees and retain the BST property. 
The approach im using is to flatten the trees and store them in arrays. 
The function above flattens my first tree and stores it in the array[] .

I want a function which would take the rootnode and blank array[] as input and RETURNS me a flattened tree with all the nodes into an array.

Answer (score 0):

As you are doing, if you want to merge 2 binary search tree, the best way is:
   1)Flatten trees into sorted lists.
   2)Merge lists.
   3)Transform the merged list to a BST.

You can implement the function you are looking for easily this way:

```
BinarySearchTree* arrayToTree(int arr[], int start, int end) {
  if (start > end) return NULL;
  int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
  BinarySearchTree *node = new BinarySearchTree(arr[mid]);
  node->left = arrayToTree(arr, start, mid-1);
  node->right = arrayToTree(arr, mid+1, end);
  return node;
}

BinarySearchTree* arrayToTree(int arr[], int n) {
  return arrayToTree(arr, 0, n-1);
}
```